# How do I code in a QR code manual input that has separate boxes for each digit?

Tags: forms, qr-code

I'm working on a webpage where people can either scan or manually enter their 6-digit QR code on this page. I designed it to have an input with 6 square boxes for people to enter their codes. Below is the code I have where I use Bootstrap form and just resized the columns to create smaller inputs.

Comment: Like this:https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FLoVqe.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F41698357%2Fhow-to-partition-input-field-to-appear-as-separate-input-fields-on-screen&tbnid=5O-s77DzGcngOM&vet=12ahUKEwiX9ZLrxsznAhUCL60KHUmjD_cQMygCegUIARDhAQ..i&docid=FTtIMFO93h7RqM&w=543&h=142&q=HTML%20form%20digit%20input&ved=2ahUKEwiX9ZLrxsznAhUCL60KHUmjD_cQMygCegUIARDhAQ#imgrc=5O-s77DzGcngOM&imgdii=dRVcsiqqln6UcM

Comment: you need to show code snippets or reference, and be more clear with your English